# protractor select option in ie promise false

Tags: select, protractor

I have a test that required from me to select option, sound easy yes? so not in ie.

I'm building tests in protractor with

> SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,

the code in the HTML

```
<div class="ims-col-14 text-center has-padding-top-3 has-padding-left-4 has-padding-right-4 has-border-left" style="height: 34px;">
    <select class="ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" data-ng-disabled="vm.disableDocument(document)" ng-change="vmDoc.status_OnChange(document,'BYPASS')" ng-model="document.status" ng-options="opt.key as opt.value for opt in vm.documentStatuses[document.documentType.type]">
    <option selected="selected" value="string:MISSING"></option>
    <option value="string:BYPASS" label="2">2</option>
    <option value="string:RECEIVED_MANUALLY" label="3">3</option>
    <option value="string:NOT_REQUIRED" label="4">4</option>
    </select>
    </div>
```

I want to select the option with BYPASS but non that the solution I found solve me issue 
their is 4 select in the document

```
  select_doc:ElementArrayFinder =  element.all(By.css("imscore-process-documents select.ng-pristine"));
```

I came close to solve the issue with robot action , but after the open the select the option not been selected

```
await browser.actions().mouseMove(this.select_doc.get(0)).perform();
await browser.sleep(1000);
await browser.actions().click().perform();
await browser.sleep(1000);
await browser.actions().mouseMove({x: 10, y: 20}).perform();
await browser.sleep(1000);
await browser.actions().click().perform();
await browser.sleep(2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a function that selects the dropdown using the option number. Something like this:

```
let selectbyNum = async function ( element, num ) {
  if (num){
    let options = await $$(by.tagName('option')); 
    await options[num].click();
  }
};
```

This should allow you to select the element according to the number. 
If this doesn't work, you can do something like this:

```
await element(by.css("div.ims-col-14 option [value='string:BYPASS']")).click();
```

I also don't see a ng-pristine class so I wonder how you are selecting all elements from `element.all(By.css("imscore-process-documents select.ng-pristine"));`
One of the two should work. Give it a shot!!